# Merge queries into 1 for sorting

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the query to get users

```
SELECT * FROM users
```

then for each user, I need to get information

```
SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM users WHERE refer_id='{$users['user_id']}' 
SELECT COUNT(user_id), SUM(amount) FROM visitors WHERE user_id='{$users['user_id']}' 
SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM sales WHERE user_id='{$users['user_id']}'
```

They are united by user_id from the first query. I need to merge this queries for order by every count

Comment: Could you post a few of rows of the expected output, please?

Comment: If you want to select data from multiple tables you can use JOIN. But indeed, post some data of the output you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with nested subqueries:

```
select u.user_id, count(*) as numusers,
       (SELECT COUNT(user_id), FROM visitors v WHERE v.user_id = u.user_id) as NumVisitors,
       (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM visitors v WHERE v.user_id = u.user_id) as VisitorAmount,
       (SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM sales s WHERE s.user_id = u.user_id) as NumSales
from users u
group by u.user_id;
```

You can also do this by joining pre-aggregated queries:

```
select u.user_id, v.NumVisitors, v.VisitorAmount, s.NumSales
from (select u.user_id, count(*) as NumUsers
      from users u
      group by u.user_id
     ) u left outer join
     (select v.user_id, count(user_id) as NumVisitors, sum(amount) as VisitorAmount
      from visitors v
      group by v.user_id
     ) v
     on u.user_id = v.visitor_id left outer join
     (select s.user_id, count(user_id) as NumSales
      from sales s
      group by s.user_id
     ) s
     on s.user_id = u.user_id;
```